# collapse comment area in Razor syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm working on a new app that has large areas I would like to comment out while I work on different parts of the page.

Is there a way to collapse the commented areas in Visual Studio 2010 in a c# razor file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can!

Select the code/comments or what ever you want to collapse...

Then, right click and choose **Collapse Tag**.

The only drawback is that it doesn't persist. As soon as you close the view it won't be there when you re-open it.

The only other suggestion I could make is separate parts that you're working on into Partial Views. That way you can work on smaller pieces and won't have to worry about collapsing anything.